# React Native 'expo-asset requires expo-file-system package to be installed and linked' ERROR

Tags: react-native, expo

I run my react native on android simulator and I got this error:

```
expo-asset requires expo-file-system package to be installed and linked
```

[image]

On iPhone its works fine and there is not error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3027

you should run the following command:

```
npm install react-native@0.55.2
```

Comment: changing the version does not works have tried. In my project if I am using a vector icons or gradient package  it displays me those above errors. Need much better answer for this